# Unknown column 'blogcats.id' in 'where clause' ,'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

I am trying to refer Blogs table To Blogcats Table through Blogrefs. When i tried to retrieve blogs by a specific category id it returns the following error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message '42S22, 1054, Unknown column 'blogcats.id' in 'where clause'' in D:\Project Files\cms\application\libraries\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php on line 312
( ! ) ActiveRecord\DatabaseException: 42S22, 1054, Unknown column 'blogcats.id' in 'where clause' in D:\Project Files\cms\application\libraries\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php on line 312
```

Youll notice that it returns an unknown column error.

THis is my code.

```
$joins  = 'LEFT JOIN blogrefs ON(blogs.id = blogrefs.blog_id) LEFT JOIN blogcats ON(blogrefs.blogcat_id = blogcats.id)';

$conditions = array("(blogcats.id = ? OR blogcats.parent_id = ?) AND blogs.status $st= ? OR (blogs.title LIKE '%$keyword%' OR blogs.content LIKE'%$keyword%')",$category,$category,$status);

$result = Blog::find('all',array(
    'joins'         => $joins,
    'conditions'    => $conditions,
    'group'         => 'blogs.id'
));
```

Comment: You have not used active records here

Comment: Assuming `Blog` is a PHPActiveRecord model he has.

Comment: At risk of stating the obvious: Do you have an `id` column in your `blogcats` table?

Comment: You need to output the query generated so that we can at least look at that.
It's something like `echo Model::table()->last_sql`